# npm install causing peerinvalid errors in Angular2 app

Tags: angular, npm

I have no issues with this until today when I tried to install a new package. Now I can't even do an

```
npm install
```

and I get the following errors

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program      Files (
x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package rxjs does not satisfy its siblings'peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/core@2.1.2 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/http@2.1.2 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.1.2 wants rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular-in-memory-web-api@0.1.17 wants rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4
```

Here are my dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.10",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
"angular2-select": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.39",
"zone.js": "^0.6.25"
```

},

I have tried deleting the node_modules folder and get the same thing.
Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like your angular-in-memory-web-api package needs rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4 not -beta.12

Comment: ok I am actually not even sure what that package is for or if it is being used. (meaning the angular-in-memory-web-api package)

Comment: I uninstalled that and the errors went away. But not sure if it was needed :) App is running fine so we'll see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your angular-in-memory-web-api package needs 
`rxjs@5.0.0-rc.4` not 
`rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12` you may need to uninstall that package